# NavigationDestination triggered from alert

Tags: swiftui, ios16

I'm trying to launch a new view when the "Host" button on the alert is pressed, but I'm having difficulty determining where to place the NavigationDestination in the new iOS 16. Here is my current code. I want the user to be able to press "Host Game" and then be prompted to enter their name before loading the "Lobby View."

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @State private var playerName: String = ""
    @State private var isGameHosted: Bool = false
    @State private var currentGame: Game?
    @State private var showingNameAlert: Bool = false
    @State private var gameID: String?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                Text("Game")
                    .bold()
                    .font(Font.custom("Futura", size: 60))
                    .foregroundColor(.red)

                Button(action: {
                    self.showingNameAlert = true
                }) {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .overlay(
                            Text("Host Game")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .font(Font.custom("Futura", size: 20))
                                .bold()
                        )
                }
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isGameHosted) {
                    LobbyView(game: currentGame!)
                }

                Button(action: {
                    print("Join Game Tapped")
                }) {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .overlay(
                            Text("Join Game")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .font(Font.custom("Futura", size: 20))
                                .bold()
                        )
                }

                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .alert("Enter Your Name", isPresented: $showingNameAlert) {
            TextField("Name", text: $playerName)
                .textInputAutocapitalization(.words)
            Button("Host", action: {
                if self.playerName != "" {
                    self.hostGame()
                    self.showingNameAlert = false
                    self.isGameHosted = true
                }
            })
            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) { }
        } message: {
            Text("Please enter your name to host the game.")
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code? As far as I can see, it works.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the question is about where to put the `navigationDestination`.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationdestination(for:destination:)) is not very specific, although it does identify some special cases:

> Add this view modifer to a view inside a `NavigationStack`

> Do not put a navigation destination modifier inside a “lazy” container, like `List` or `LazyVStack`. These containers create child views only when needed to render on screen. Add the navigation destination modifier outside these containers so that the navigation stack can always see the destination.

As a general rule, I would suggest adding it to the parent container. So in your case, I would probably put it on the `VStack` rather than on a `Button`. But it's not wrong to have it on a `Button` here, since the parent container does not use lazy loading.